# Windows Server 2003 R2 SP2 can't access the internet

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-server-2003-r2

Our 64-bit windows server can no longer access the internet although it is a web-server that is hosting webpages accessible by the internet. Since this dilemma the server can no longer receive windows updates or Symantec virus definitions.

We have checked our firewalls so nothing is blocked. Any insight on why this issue happened would be appreciated.

Also the server is running IE6 which we have been trying to update.

I am able to ping other servers in the same subnet except the gateway yet the domain controller in this subnet cannot ping the gateway either yet able to access the internet.

Comment: Can you ping your default gateway? Can you ping loopback?

Comment: Did you just update them? Did something change?

Comment: Nothing changed.
Ping Loopback - Yes
Ping Gateway - No (Although I get a MAC address)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

1. Update your NIC drivers.
2. Reset winsock - netsh winsock reset c:\winsock.log
3. Reset TCP/IP - netsh int ip reset c:\ipreset.log
4. Reboot
5. Setup your static IP address again (if it's static) and try accessing the internet. This will also give you a good opportunity to ensure you have the correct IP, subnet, and gateway settings.

Comment: Oh I'm very sure we have the correct IP address settings since they were never changed.

Comment: Turns out our firewall administrator was being a douche. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar problem but it went away with the installation of Firefox 4.0. Download this older version of firefox from `filehorse.com`